# Как создать ImageType для компонента Form в Silex

Tags: form, symfony2, silex

Надо создать собственный компонент форма для Symfony/Form используя фреймворк Silex для отображение картинки(капчи) в форме.

Установлены следующие компоненты:
- silex/silex 1.3
- symfony/form 2.7

Добавил элемент ImageType:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{

  function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder,array $options){
  }

  function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
      return array("attr"=>array('src'=>"/img/image.png"));
  }

  function getParent(){
      return "form";
  }

  public function getName()
  {
      return 'image';
  }
}
```

Но в результате выводится тэг `div`.
Как создать собственный элемент для отображение изображения в форме?
т.е. тега `img`.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш `buildForm` будет примерно так выглядеть. Если Ваш `ImageType` подразумевает наличие только изображения

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label'    => 'image'
            ))
        ;
    }
```

Я не знаю хорошая ли это практика. Но мои `buildForm` описывают полностью сущность. При таком подходе мои формы имеют следующий вид:

```
{% form_theme form 'SyliusWebBundle::forms.html.twig' %}
<fieldset>
    {{ form_widget(form) }} 
</fieldset>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

форма выводится на основе описанного `buildForm` и если на форме `n` полей то этого достаточно чтобы вывести работающую форму.

---

если нужно вывести изображение на форме, возможно это то что Вам нужно

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
     public function getExtendedType()
     {
         return 'file';
     }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('image_path'));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
    if (array_key_exists('image_path', $options)) {
        $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();

        if (null !== $parentData) {
            $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
            $imageUrl = $accessor->getValue($parentData, $options['image_path']);
        } else {
             $imageUrl = null;
        }

        $view->vars['image_url'] = $imageUrl;
    }
    }
```

в представлении выводите Ваше изображение и эллемент ввода капчи

```
{% block file_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}

    {{ block('form_widget') }}
    {% if image_url is not null %}
        <img src="{{ asset(image_url) }}"/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_row(form.capcha) }}
    {% endspaceless %} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: если я показал пример неверного использования компонентов - хотелось бы увидеть корректные примеры

Comment: Ты показал пример создание своего элемента на основе существующих. Мне же надо создать с нуля, базовый элемент.
По твоему примеру создаётся загрузка файла.

Comment: а разве изображение это не файл?
Я описал представление **buildForm** на основе Вашего вопроса. Вывод формы использовал свой, у Вас лишь изменится наследование форм

Comment: Наверное я не корректно задал вопрос. мне нужно не загрузить файл, а вывести картинку, т.е. тэг `img` для отображения капчи.

Comment: тогда это у Вас строка. Если конечно Вы храните изображение на диске. Опишите желаемое, Вы хотите чтобы на форме присуствовало статическое изображение?

Comment: в форме должно отображать текстовое поле для ввода текста, а перед ним тег `<img src="/captca.jpg' />`

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26430/discussion-between---and-username).

Comment: Похоже это то что нужно, но только вот шаблон не подхватывается... как подключить шаблон в симфони написано много. как это сделать в силекс не нашёл

Comment: у Вас в бандле должен лежать шаблон, но как показывает практика он редко Вам может пригодится. Переопреоделить его можно в конфигах  `defaults: { _template }`, либо воссоздав путь к дефолтному представлению в `app/Resourses`

Answer (score 0):

Задача решалась просто:

1. Нужно создать свой класс расширения наследуемый от `AbstractType`
2. создать отдельный шаблон, например `custom_widgets.html.twig` который должен содержать блок `captcha_widget`:

```html
{%- block captcha_widget -%}
    <img src="{{ path('captcha') }}" /><br> 
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }} 
{%- endblock captcha_widget -%}
```

3. при создание сервис провайдера twig указать указать файл с пользовательски шаблоном

```html
$app->register(new \Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), [
    'twig.path' => $app['twig.path'],
    'twig.options' => $app['twig.options'],
    'twig.form.templates' => [
       'custom_widgets.html.twig'
    ]
]);
```